# Optimized way to retrieve IDs through has_many :through association

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have 3 model as following : 
(I'm also describing the database structure in case of anyone not familiar with RubyOnRails is able to help me)

---

**Thread.rb**

```
class Thread
  has_many :thread_profils
  has_many :profils, :through => :thread_profils
end
```

Table **threads**

```
integer: id (PK)
```

---

**ThreadProfil.rb**

```
class ThreadProfil
  belongs_to :thread
  belongs_to :profil
end
```

Table **thread_profils**

```
integer: id (PK)
integer: thread_id (FK)
integer: profil_id (FK)
```

---

**Profil.rb**

```
class Profil
end
```

Table **profils**

```
integer: id (PK)
```

---

In one of my controllers I am looking for the most optimized way to find the Threads  IDs that has include ***exactly*** two profils (the current one, a some other one) :

I got my `current_profil.id` and another `profil.id` and I can't figure out a simple way to get that collection/list/array of `Thread.id`, while processing the fewer SQL request.

---

For now the only solution I found is the following one, which I don't consider as being "optimized" at all.

```
thread_profils = ThreadProfil.where(:profil_id => current_profil.id)
thread_ids = thread_profils.map do | association |
  profils = Thread.find(association.thread_id).profils.map do | profil | 
      profil.id if profil.id != current_profil.id
  end.compact
  if (profils - [id]).empty?
    association.thread_id
  end
end.compact
```

That is processing the following SQL queries :

```
SELECT `thread_profils`.* FROM `thread_profils` WHERE `thread_profils`.`profil_id` = [current_profil.id]
```

And for each result :

```
SELECT `threads`.* FROM `threads` WHERE `threads`.`id` = [thread_id] LIMIT 1

SELECT `profils`.* FROM `profils` INNER JOIN `thread_profils` ON `profils`.`id` = `thread_profils`.`profil_id` WHERE `thread_profils`.`thread_id` = [thread_id]
```

---

Is there any light way to do that, either with rails or directly with SQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the following query in sql:

```
SELECT array_agg(thread_id) FROM "thread_profils" WHERE "thread_profils"."profil_id" = 1 GROUP BY profil_id HAVING count(thread_id) =2
```

note: `array_agg` is a postgres aggregate function. Mysql has `group_concat` which would give you a comma-delimited string of IDs instead of an array.

This sql was generated by the following Rails code:

```
 ThreadProfil.select('array_agg(mythread_id)').where(profil_id: 1).group(:profil_id).having("count(thread_id) =2").take
```

This generates the right query, but the result is not meaningful as a ThreadProfil - still, you might be able to work further with this to get what you want.